# ListView item not changing background

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to change the background of a listview item when it's pressed, and despite having tried what has been mentioned in other SO posts the item refuses to change background when clicked.

What I'm I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT: What I want to achieve:**

[image]

This is how the default listview reacts when clicking an item (talking about the background change), but since I'm using custom list elements layout the list doesn't respond to clicks at all and is very dull, so I'm trying to achieve similar behaviour with the background changing whenever I click a list element.

I have this simple selector:

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state" />
</selector>
```

**selected_state.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/darkblue" />
    </shape>
```

---

I tried setting it to the selector of the listview and making the list view single choice

**Main layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
...
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ListView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/listViewCentral"
                            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector" />
                </LinearLayout>
 ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

**List view item:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector">

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

And I used `OnItemClick` listener to set the state to selected

**Main activity:**

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewCentral);
        list.setAdapter(stringAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new TsClickListener());
```

**Listener:**

```
public class TsClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        view.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Logcat is empty (no errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem after all was the `OnItemClick` event wasn't being fired at all, and the solution was to add the '`clickable`' attribute to the `RelativeLayout` of my list view element's layout and set it to **true**, everything works fine then.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:clickable="true" <-- Problem
    android:background="@drawable/selector">

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the property `android:state_focused`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state" />            
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state" />
</selector>
```